# Character encoding in raw_input Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I try to run the following script in command line under Windows7. The default character encoding is ascii. When I try to run the script I get something weird instead of "Kérem adja meg a kimenet elnevezését! >".

The encoding of the python file is UTF-8. I have tried several ways to solve the problem without success. What am I doing wrong. There absolutely no problem on mac.

```
#! /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import difflib
from sys import argv
import re
import fileinput
import webbrowser


script, filename1, filename2 = argv

# Itt kezdjük el a szövegek összehasonlítását

compare = open(filename1, 'r').read()
compare_lines = str(compare).splitlines()

compare2 = open(filename2, 'r').read()
compare_lines2 = str(compare2).splitlines()

d = difflib.HtmlDiff()
kulonbseg = d.make_file(compare_lines, compare_lines2)

kulonbsegek = raw_input("Kérem adja meg a kimenet elnevezését! >")
file = open(kulonbsegek, 'w')
file.write(str(kulonbseg))
file.close()

for line in fileinput.FileInput(kulonbsegek ,inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8")
    print line

new = 2
url = kulonbsegek
chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

# Windows
# chrome_path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: what if you `decode("ISO-8859-2")` or `decode("windows-1250")` the input? Maybe followed by `.encode("utf-8")`?

Comment: I tried all the combination and I get weird character or the following error message:

C:\Users\user\Desktop\TT>python compare.py regi.txt regi1.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 27, in <module>
    text_code = text.decode("windows-1250").encode("UTF-8")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1: charac
ter maps to <undefined>

Comment: I meant `compare = open(filename1, 'r').read().decode("ISO-8859-2")`. "latin1", "latin2" or "cp-1252" might also be worth trying.

Comment: [This](https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projects/chared/?url=http://www.bipolarisvilag.hu/oldal/hirek/news.php?article_id=209&language=hungarian) might help

Comment: There is absolutely no problem with the file which is created by the script. The only problem is with the raw_input text which appears in the commandline (raw_input("Kérem adja meg a kimenet elnevezését! >").

Answer (score 1):

Your windows cmd has some encoding which don't compatible with UTF-8 so you are getting weird symbols.

You could check it by executing `chcp` in cmd.

For UTF-8 you should set it to `chcp 65001` and check some other [settings](https://superuser.com/questions/237081/whats-the-code-page-of-utf-8/272184#272184) of your cmd.

Comment: Ok! it is working perfectly with that font. However I don't want the users to type chcp command every time they use the script. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    input_msg = "Kérem adja meg a kimenet elnevezését! >".decode('utf-8').encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
    kulonbsegek = raw_input(input_msg)
```